# How can I create thumbnail preview icons in windows explorer for document files on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-c++, thumbnails, windows-shell

I'm creating an application for Windows 7 that reads documents, and I'd like to enable the functionality where the cover of the document can be previewed in the thumbnail icon. I know I'll have to create the thumbnail image, but how do I feed that image to explorer so it uses that thumbnail image for that particular file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a [thumbnail provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776855%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and register it during your program's setup program.

Suggested reading: [Recipe Thumbnail Provider Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)